# .Exe file won't execute correctly

Tags: c, exe

I'm new to the programming world, recently I began my programming path with C, and because of that I made a program that determines if a number is whether perfect or not. I use Code::Blocks IDE, and it works just fine, the problem is when I click the option "Build and run", the IDE executes the program and works perfectly, but when I select the .exe file from my desktop, it opens up, but doesn't show any output, the window just closes suddenly. Does someone have any idea on how to solve this issue?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
        int N;
        int j;
        int Sum = 0;

        printf("Input a number.\n");
        scanf("%d",&N);

        for (j = 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (N%j==0)
            {
                Sum+=j;
            }

        }
        if (Sum==N)
        {
            printf("The number is perfect.\n");
        } else {
            printf("The number is not perfect.\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

[Running program with Code::Blocks Build and run option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lVFS.png)

[The only part of the Desktop located .exe that I can reach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcMhJ.png)

If someone can suggest a solution, I will be very thankful!

Comment: Run command line programs from a command line, not a gui.

Comment: Your program exits as soon as it completes. Codeblocks is a debugger so it is set up to keep the window open even after the program exits. However, launching an application from the Windows UI will not keep the window open after the program exits (why should it). Either your program needs to not exit immediately or better still run your program from the command line (e.g. CMD or powershell).

Comment: @kaylum The OP said it works with Code::Blocks. Why not just use that?

Comment: @KeithThompson I assumed the OP wanted to run the program directly outside the IDE for a specific reason. But yes, if it's still part of development then continuing to run in Codeblocks would be a good way.

Answer (score 2):

As it was said, the program exits immediatly after it's completion. If you want to run the program, executing it by double click, you can place a pause condition in the program, for instance if you put `getchar();` just before the `return 0;` statement, it will only exit after it receives an input from the keyboard, that is after you enter a key.